accessLevel: 'private' is not putting file into s3 private directory
I have a React project using aws-amplify version 6.1.4 . I'm only using amplify for auth and storage management and not for CD/CI.
I want to put my file in the already existing "private" directory. However, my file without adding anything related to directory The official Amplify documentation wasn't helpful I ended up coming across some repos and stackoverflow questions that suggested adding
options: { accessLevel: 'private' } 

to my uploadData request. However, after adding accessLevel (see below), it doesn't upload to either the private or public directory. No upload at all even though there is no error given in the console.log(result). Once I remove accessLevel: 'private' it reverts back to uploading the files in the public directory.
Here's my Amplify.configure:
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        Cognito: {
            identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
            userPoolClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID
        }
    },
    Storage: {
        S3: {
            bucket: process.env.REACT_APP_S3_BUCKET,
            region: process.env.REACT_APP_S3_REGION
        }
    }
});

Here's a sample of my request with the added accessLevel: 'private',
import { uploadData } from 'aws-amplify/storage';

...
                    const result = await uploadData({
                        key,
                        data: blob,
                        options: {
                            accessLevel: 'private',
                            contentType,
                            metadata: {
                                environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
                                resourceId: photoResult.data.id,
                                resourceType: resourceTypes.PHOTO
                            },
                            onProgress: ({ transferredBytes, totalBytes }) => {
                                console.log(`Uploading photo: ${transferredBytes}/${totalBytes}`);
                            }
                        }
                    }).result;

                    console.log("Upload result:", result);

When I hover over accessLevel in the code above, this pops up:
(property) WriteOptions.accessLevel?: StorageAccessLevel
which makes me think that this is the correct place to put it. However, it still doesn't upload anything after adding accessLevel.
Here are the contents of:
node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/dist/esm/singleton/Storage/types.d.ts
import { AtLeastOne } from '../types';
export type StorageAccessLevel = 'guest' | 'protected' | 'private';
export interface S3ProviderConfig {
    S3: {
        bucket?: string;
        region?: string;
        /**
         * Internal-only configuration for testing purpose. You should not use this.
         *
         * @internal
         */
        dangerouslyConnectToHttpEndpointForTesting?: string;
    };
}
export type StorageConfig = AtLeastOne<S3ProviderConfig>;
type StoragePrefixResolver = (params: {
    accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel;
    targetIdentityId?: string;
}) => Promise<string>;
export interface LibraryStorageOptions {
    S3: {
        prefixResolver?: StoragePrefixResolver;
        defaultAccessLevel?: StorageAccessLevel;
        isObjectLockEnabled?: boolean;
    };
}
export {};

I tried a few experiments based on the values in the Storage/types.d.ts (which curiously doesn't have "public" as an option):
export type StorageAccessLevel = 'guest' | 'protected' | 'private';


I tried changing accessLevel to "protected" and the upload created a new "protected" directory and put the files in there.
When I changed accessLevel to "guest" it wrote the files in the public directory.
But when I changed the accessLevel to private, it didn't write the files at all.

I also asked Amazon Q for help and was told:
"The search results indicate that the access level needs to be explicitly granted within the defineStorage configuration"
which led me to these docs
Reading through this part of the documentation points me back to Amplify.configure() because the files added like resource.ts would eventually get used by Amplify.configure by writing something like this:
import { defineStorage } from '@aws-amplify/backend';


export const storage = defineStorage({
    name: 'web-app',
    access: (allow) => ({
        'public/*': [
            allow.guest.to(['read']),
            allow.authenticated.to(['read', 'write', 'get']),
          ],
          'protected/{entity_id}/*': [
            allow.authenticated.to(['read']),
            allow.entity('identity').to(['read', 'write', 'get'])
          ],
          'private/{entity_id}/*': [
            allow.entity('identity').to(['read', 'write', 'get'])
          ]
    })
});

But it's not clear if resource.ts is just for use cases where you are using Amplify to deploy your app and CD/CI or for my case where I just want to use amplify for auth and storage. There must be code out that only modifies Amplify.configure() directly and not have to use a lot of extra files to generate it. I just can't seem to find it.
Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working (no upload at all) and why there are no errors? Is there something else I have to do elsewhere like in Amplify.configure()?
